Why $S^{-1}I \subseteq \text{Nilrad}(S^{-1}A)$
Let $A$ be a ring and $I$ a proper ideal of $A$. With $S = 1 + I$, show that $S^{-1}I \subseteq \text{Nilrad}(S^{-1}A)$.
I know that the nilradical of a ring $R$, denoted $\text{Nilrad}(R)$, is the set of all nilpotent elements of $R$, i.e., for all $ r \in R$ there exists some $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ with $ r^n = 0 $. I'm unsure how to proceed with this inclusion.

The statement is false.

This question has already been asked here by the same user. -1

@Numeral it's the same but the over one is said to be closed

You should edit the original question to address the reason it was closed.

@Mark, I thought that but my professor said it's true with the condition in my question

@Numeral, I did the modifications as they suggested but it didn't work

This is false and there are many counterexamples. For example, $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $I = 2\mathbb{Z}$.

@MartinBrandenburg, thanks a lot, I think it is true only if $I$ is nilpotent too
